# After deleting files I do not get any more space on my hard drive and files are not in trash

Tags: delete, trash

I am deleting files from my filesystem because I am running out of space but I do not get any more free space after deleting them. I cannot locate these files and they are not in trash. 
I do not know if that makes any difference but I have deleted some of these files being logged as root.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it make all the difference because root has a separate trash.

To empty it you may paste this on terminal:  `gksudo nautilus '/root/.Trash/'` to open the trash and then remove it's files.

Answer (score 0):

You might also hold the shift key down and then hit the delete button.(shift-delete)  These files will not go into trash but they will be permanently deleted, so these files will not be recoverable.