# How to freeup space in external hardrive

Tags: nautilus, delete, trash, mint

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Linux Mint 18 and Elementary OS all on external hard drive (all OSs are installed on different partitions). I was using Linux Mint to recover some data from SD card using "Photorec" and in this process the partition on which mint was installed got fully used leaving no free space. When I restarted the computer, mint didn't allow me to log-in giving an error message that due to no free space you cannot login, hence contact your administrator.

In order to free-up some space I logged into Ubuntu and deleted some files from the partition on which mint was installed. Even after deleting files of approx 5GB the properties show that there is no free space in the said partition.

Now I don't know where these files, which I have been deleted, have gone and how to free up some space. One thing that came into my mind was that the deleted files might have gone into trash. But there was nothing in the trash of Ubuntu. I don't know how to access the trash of mint using Ubuntu to check whether deleted files have gone into mint trash folder.

Please help me freeing up some space in my mint partition using Ubuntu.

PS: As the folders of mint were locked when I logged into Ubuntu, hence I deleted the files after unlocking the folders with the help of "sudo nautilus" command.

Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After deleting files I do not get any more space on my hard drive and files are not in trash](http://askubuntu.com/questions/57043/after-deleting-files-i-do-not-get-any-more-space-on-my-hard-drive-and-files-are)

Answer (score 0):

Use Nautilus' option of seeing hidden files.  Look for a file named `.Trash` under the `root` account of the OS installation and delete that one.  Also look for the `.Trash` folder under the UID account that you used when you where working with the drive.

You can check your effective `UID` with the command: `echo $UID`.  Then look at the /etc/passwd file for the UID on the Mint drive... the drive that you are trying to recover the space to.

Answer (score 0):

> One thing that came into my mind was that the deleted files might have gone into trash. But there was nothing in the trash of Ubuntu.

There is no "trash of Ubuntu", there is one trash for each user. You ran Nautilus as `root` with `sudo nautilus` therefore you have two options.

1. Run `sudo nautilus` again from Ubuntu and empty the trash there.
2. Figure out where the `.Trash-0` hidden folder is in the Mint partition and manually clean it with the terminal, e.g.:

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /path/to/.Trash-0
   ```

Comment: @SaadAwaN You're welcome.  You might consider marking the answer resolved by clicking the check mark.  This would make it easy for someone having a similar issue to find workable solutions.